# the "new" word changes a function to an object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, this

I'm stuck in  some issue, a had a function like this:

```
var sayHi = function(string){
  console.log(string + '' + this.name);
};
```

then i need to do :

```
sayHi = giveContext(sayHi,{"name":"moe"});
```

and then I do :

```
function giveContext(func,obj){

  var fn = func;
  fn.prototype.name = obj.name;

  var myFn = new fn;

  return myFn; 

}
```

and the expected behavior would it be :

```
sayHi('Hello')  // ==> "Hello moe"
```

the thing is that the "new" keyword in givecontext returns an object instead of a function.
and I'm only getting a

```
undefined moe 
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

I'm missing something ?

Comment: Why are you assigning `sayHi` twice?

Comment: sorry, I mistyped that, it shouldn't be assigned twice, edited already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `new fn` it will call the function `fn` as the constructor of an object, and the result is the object that was created.

Basically this:

```
var myFn = new fn;
```

works as:

```
var myFn = {}; // create an object
fn.call(myFn); // call the constructor with the object as context
```

(There are more things going on of course, but that is the important stuff for now.)

So, the function `giveContext` doesn't give a context to a function and return it, instead it will call the function as a constructor of an object and return the object. The code inside the function will be called already (that's why there is a console output at all), and when you are trying to use the return vale from `giveContext` as a function you will get an error as it's not a function at all.

There is already a built in [method `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) that sets the context for a function:

```
sayHi = sayHi.bind({"name":"moe"});
```

(Note the support information for the method though, it's not supported in iE 8 for example.)

You can also do the same without the `bind` method by creating a function that calls the function:

```
function giveContext(f, obj) {
  return function(){
    return f.apply(obj, arguments);
  };
}
```

Comment: yeah, but that's the tricky part, the native method "bind" can't be used in this exercise

Comment: @flaalf: I added an alternative without using `bind` above.

Comment: i forgot to mention, the giveContext function is in another script, should that interfere with the apply method ?

Comment: @flaalf: I adjusted the code to use `apply` to include the arguments passed to the function right after posting the comment. Check that you have the current version. Regarding the `giveContext` being in another script, once the code is loaded and parsed it doesn't matter where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, JavaScript is object-oriented, so when you say `new fn`, it creates a new object.  In your setup, your function has a name property, so you should be using `"Hello " + sayHi.name` to get the results you expect.

You're going to want to read though this to get a good overview: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: the original sayHi function can't be changed,I mean, the goal of this exercise is to insert the "name" variable into the sayHi function